# AndroidX jetifier: Failed to transform file 'android-all-9-robolectric-4913185-2.jar' to match attributes using transform JetifyTransform

Tags: java, android, robolectric, androidx, android-jetifier

After migrating to AndroidX, I receive this error when building `Failed to transform 'C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.robolectric\android-all\9-robolectric-4913185-2\92c6ca3712d7a06f76f70655ec81162ff372fb19\android-all-9-robolectric-4913185-2.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 2 of 3-byte UTF-8 sequence.. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.) To disable Jetifier, set android.enableJetifier=false in your gradle.properties file.`
 when running unit tests. I do need the enableJetifier set on true.

Does anybody have any idea why this is happening or how to solve it? I just added more code to give a better insight. All the versions are in the versions array.

gradle.properties:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Versions:

```
ext.versions = [
        androidSupport    : '28.0.0',
        otto              : '1.3.8',
        retrofit          : '2.4.0',
        okhttp3           : '3.11.0',
        animator          : '2.2.3',
        gson              : '2.8.5',
        joda              : '2.9.3',
        commonsLang3      : '3.4',
        commonsIo         : '2.5',
        commonsCollections: '3.2.2',
        commonsCodec      : '1.10',
        espresso          : '3.1.0-beta01',
        hamcrest          : '1.3',
        junit             : '4.12',
        mockito           : '1.10.19',
        powerMock         : '1.6.5',
        dagger            : '2.17',
        parcel            : '1.1.5',
        butterKnife       : '9.0.0-SNAPSHOT',

        robolectric       : '4.0-beta-1',
        assertj           : '3.11.1',
        awaitility        : '3.1.2',
        material          : '1.0.0'
]
```

Build.gradle:

```
    dependencies {
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha2'
        implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
        implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
        implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
        implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
        implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'
        implementation('androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0') {
            force true
        }

        implementation "com.google.guava:guava:$versions.guava"

        implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$versions.dagger"
        annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$versions.dagger"

        implementation "com.squareup:otto:$versions.otto"
        implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$versions.retrofit"
        implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$versions.retrofit"
        implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$versions.okhttp3"
        implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$versions.material"

        implementation "jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:$versions.animator"

        implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:$versions.gson"
        implementation "net.danlew:android.joda:$versions.joda"

        implementation "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:$versions.commonsLang3"
        implementation "commons-collections:commons-collections:$versions.commonsCollections"
        implementation "commons-io:commons-io:$versions.commonsIo"
        implementation "commons-codec:commons-codec:$versions.commonsCodec"

        implementation "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:$versions.picasso"

        implementation "org.parceler:parceler-api:$versions.parcel"
        annotationProcessor "org.parceler:parceler:$versions.parcel"

        implementation "com.jakewharton:butterknife:$versions.butterKnife"
        annotationProcessor "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:$versions.butterKnife"



// test dependencies
    testImplementation "junit:junit:$versions.junit"
    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:$versions.mockito"
    testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-core:$versions.powerMock"
    testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:$versions.powerMock"
    testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule:$versions.powerMock"
    testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:$versions.powerMock"
    testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-classloading-xstream:$versions.powerMock"
    testImplementation "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:$versions.hamcrest"
    testImplementation "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:$versions.hamcrest"
    testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:$versions.robolectric"
    testImplementation "org.assertj:assertj-core:$versions.assertj"
    testImplementation "org.robolectric:android-all:9-robolectric-4913185-2"

    // android test dependencies
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-beta01'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.1.0-beta01'
    androidTestImplementation "junit:junit:$versions.junit"
    androidTestImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:$versions.mockito"
    androidTestImplementation "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:$versions.hamcrest"
    androidTestImplementation "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:$versions.hamcrest"
    androidTestImplementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit-mock:$versions.retrofit"
    androidTestImplementation "com.google.guava:guava:$versions.guava"
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:$versions.espresso", {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:$versions.espresso", {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$versions.espresso", {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    androidTestImplementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$versions.dagger"
    androidTestAnnotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$versions.dagger"
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation "org.awaitility:awaitility:$versions.awaitility"
    }
```

Comment: Please attach both of your `build.gradle` files to the question and `gradle.properties`

Answer (score 2):

It might be a bug with Jetifier. Try adding this to your project gradle:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-processor:1.0.0-beta02'
    }
}
```

If you're using databinding you might need to add this to your application gradle dependencies:

```
annotationProcessor 'com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-core:1.0.0-beta02'
```

and if you're using kotlin then you need these two

```
kapt 'com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-core:1.0.0-beta02'
annotationProcessor 'com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-core:1.0.0-beta02'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using below dependencies fixed issue for me

```
implementation 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.12'
annotationProcessor 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.12'
```